# delete app request is giving an error: "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"

Tags: facebook, apprequests, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use the javascript method to delete an app request my app has send. I've got the APP id, the user is logged on and has an UID and Accesstoken.

The concatenated request_id is build from app request ID, user ID and accesstoken.

The script:

```
function deleteRequest(requestId) {
        FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

echo"<body onload=\"deleteRequest('".$_SESSION['requestId']."_".$_SESSION['uid']."_".$_SESSION['accessToken']."');\">";
```

The error:

error: Object

code: 803

message: "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: "

type: "OAuthException"

I have no clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

according to the doc ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting ) if you use JS its enough to give the requestID ("REQUEST_OBJECT_ID"_"USER_ID") to delete it, no need for the accessToken.

Comment: When I only use <app request id>_<user id> I get "#104 An access token is required to request this resource"

Comment: And when I use <app request id>_<access token> I receive the 803 error messages again.

I think I now have tried every possible option of combinations of app id, user id and access token. With underscores inbetween, without, all to no avail.

Comment: did you FB.init ? forget this access_token, this is not the place for it... `DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>]?
      access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]
`

Comment: Yes, I do fb.init, after the body tag. and I call the delete function in the body tag. The function itself is after the fb.init. So why do I get the accesstoken error?